# useState passed asynchronously with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a function that iterates over the urls as an array, and I need to transfer these urls to another fetch request. And then the problem arose that the hook did not work the first time. url2 is what i want to pass

```
//The function works on click
let getDataCategory = async (event) => {
let id = event.currentTarget.id;

        await fetch(`http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[parent_id][in]=${id}&filter[type]=0`,{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            },
        })
  .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    setCategoryUrl(result.data)
                    setCategorySub([...categorySub,...result.data]);
                    let url2 = `http://api.tmweb.ru/object?filter[category_id][in][]=${id}&`
                    result.data.forEach(item => {url2 += 'filter[category_id][in][]=' + item.id + '&'})
                    setCategoryUrl(url2) // This is what needs to be fetched
            });

// I pass it here, the url is generated correctly, but it is not generated from the first click
            await fetch(`${categoryUrl}&filter[type]=0`,{
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': token,
                },
            })
}
```

Tried useEffect but it didn't help much either. Everything is processed with a delay.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(categoryUrl)
        }, [categoryUrl])
```

Full code here

```
//These are the categories I'm clicking on
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[depth]=1&filter[type]=0',{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => setCategory(result.data),
            )
    }, [])

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(categoryUrl)
    }, [categoryUrl])

//Click on categories
let getDataCategory = async(event) => {
        let id = event.currentTarget.id;

//Checkbox check

        if (event.target.checked){
        await fetch(`http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[parent_id][in]=${id}&filter[type]=0`,{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
//Here subcategories and url selection
                    setCategorySub([...categorySub,...result.data]);
                    let url2 = `http://api.tmweb.ru/object?filter[category_id][in][]=${id}&`
                    result.data.forEach(item => {url2 += 'filter[category_id][in][]=' + item.id + '&'})
                    setCategoryUrl(url2)
            });

//Subcategories of subcategories should be displayed here
            await fetch(`${categoryUrl}&filter[type]=0`,{
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': token,
                },
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    console log(result)
                    setCategoryProd([...categoryProd,...result.data])
                })
//Deleting elements
        } else {
            // Remove the element from the state
            setCategorySub((prevData) => { //prevData current state
                return prevData.filter((item) => item.parent_id !== +id);
            });
            setCategoryProd((prevData) =>{
                return prevData.filter((item) => item.category_id !== +id);
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you try to use `categoryUrl` right after you use `setCategoryUrl`

`useState` behaviour is that the state is updated after a render. Thus, when you try accessing the `categoryUrl` right after you use `setCategoryUrl` the render haven't occurred yet and the url isn't being updated.

Try doing something like this:

```
if (event.target.checked){
        let currCategoryUrl = ''; // initialize an empty url

        // ... your code

                    result.data.forEach(item => {url2 += 'filter[category_id][in][]=' + item.id + '&'})
                    currCategoryUrl = url2; // here you set the temp variable within the function scope
                    setCategoryUrl(url2) // NOTE: if you need the category url only in this function and not in the state of the component you can remove the useState hook of categoryUrl.
            });

//Subcategories of subcategories should be displayed here
            await fetch(`${currCategoryUrl}&filter[type]=0`,{ // use the temp variable instead of the variable in the useState hook
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': token,
                },
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    console log(result)
                    setCategoryProd([...categoryProd,...result.data])
                })
```

There is a lot of things that you can imporve in writing your code, if you just want to make it work this is the solution but it will be better if you seperate your code to several functions (one of the ideas of functional programming is that each function has one purpose and you violate that principle)

Hope I helped and this is the solution!

Comment: Thanks really helpfull. I forgot about variables, I just tried to write data to a variable at one time and in the end I didn’t succeed, in the end I stopped using them. Yes, in the future I want to refactor the code later